# if then, iff notation for quadratic equations.

Tags: logic, notation, equivalence-relations

This is correct as far as I know:$$x^2=9 \Leftarrow x=3$$ but :$$x^2=9\Leftrightarrow x=\pm3$$ Is the $\pm $ technically acceptable notation for this relationship to be correct?

Also is it correct to write$$x^2=9\Leftrightarrow x=3,x=-3$$

Comment: Perfectly fine.

Comment: In the last equation, you should write "or" instead of the mere comma.

Comment: Yes, like $x^2=-9\Longleftrightarrow x=\pm 3i$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The question I was pondering is what the correct notation for equation solving is, especially when you have roots that are different i.e: $(x-1)^2=9\Leftrightarrow x=4  or  x=-2$

Comment: Note that the roots $3$ and $-3$ *are* indeed different. So I don't see a problem. And I wasn't asking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking in the real numbers: 
 Firstly yes the $\pm 3$ notation is correct; secondly for your second question you should use "OR" instead of a comma (","); Note that both notations mean the same thing.